# TypeScript/JavaScript inheriting constructor values?

Tags: typescript, inheritance

I've come across some code which doesn't make sense how it works: I'm admittedly newer to TypeScript but this seems like it shouldn't work:

We have 2 classes, (This is for an automation framework, playwright specifically but that shouldn't matter). A `Base` page and a `Home` page that inherits from the base page.

Base Page:

```
import type { Page } from "@playwright/test";

export abstract class BasePage {
  constructor(public readonly page: Page) {}

  async open(path: string) {
    await this.page.goto(path);
  }
}
```

Home Page:

```
import { BasePage } from "../base.page";

export default class HomePage extends BasePage {
  public readonly HomePageButton = this.page.getByTestId("home-button");

  async open() {
    await super.open("/");
  }
}
```

Trying to do something similar in my code gives errors, specifically because how is the `HomePage` know what `this.page` is? From my understanding we would need to make a new constructor and call `super(page)` right?

I do know TypeScript will create "Parameter properites" but how do I get VSCode to recognize it? If this is not the proper way to declare child classes of an abstract base class what is the recommended way?

Comment: [There is no issue with TS here](https://tsplay.dev/NlyoRm). If there is a problem with VSCode, can you describe what it is? Or if it *is* a TS problem, do provide a [mcve].

Comment: "From my understanding we would need to make a new constructor and call super(page) right?" no, if you omit the constructor definition the compiler delegates to the base class constructor implicitly. But if you define a constructor, then you are required to call super with the appropriate argument types. As VLAZ mentioned the code you posted is perfectly fine, so we cannot reproduce your problem without more information.

Comment: If you look at the JavaScript produced by [the TypeScript in the Playground link provided by @VLAZ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77009091/typescript-javascript-inheriting-constructor-values#comment135757273_77009091), you'll see why it works; it assumes a constructor exists that will provide `page` (in `arguments`). If it is not provided, that will cause an error to be thrown (just as it would if the base class were able to be constructed with an undefined argument).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HomePage` inherits the constructor of `BasePage`.

To create an object of the class `HomePage` you will need to pass the `page` parameter in the constructor.

Therefore you can use `this.page` of the base class in the child class.

Comment: Don't you need to call `super` though to use the BasePage constructor?

Comment: @msmith1114 inheritance would be quite a burden if it required that you re-define all constructors all the time just to delegate to the parent constructor. It would at least partially defeat the purpose of using it by imposing this code tax on you.

Comment: @msmith1114 Only if you explicitly define one in the subclass. There's even a lint rule in eslint typescript for "no useless constructor" https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-useless-constructor.